# Base directory and schema_version

Tags: flyway

I just tested the commandline tool and I was able to migrate my database schema changes (DDL scripts) as expected.  But I had to move all my scripts under the sql dir.

Is there a way to point flyway to the directory where my real scripts will reside (git or svn repository)?  Looks like flyway.locations is only for relative paths.

The schema_version table name and column names are all created in lower case in my database (Oracle).  The vast majority of people using Oracle are used to upper case object names and column names (default in Oracle).  I found a property in the config file to set my own table name. Is there any to get flyway to use upper case for column names?

I checked the data inserted into version_schema after my test run. All look good except that the first character of the "script" column seem to be removed.

My prefix is "db_".  Here is what I see in schema_version,

SQL> select "script" from schema_version;

script

---

b_1_0__test10.sql

b_1_1__test10.sql

b_1_0_1__test10.sql

atabase/db_2012_11_20__query.sql

<< Flyway Init >>

Answer (score 2):

Lots of questions here (It's easier if you keep them separate). I'll try my best to answer them:

1. Not currently supported. See https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/108 . Symlinking can be used as a workaround.
2. No, there is no configuration property for the column names. The schema_version table is private to Flyway and not meant for outside consumption.
3. This sounds like a bug. Please file an issue containing your configuration (OS + version, DB + version, Flyway version, config file contents) and exact steps to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks Axel. Here is the new issue - http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=380.   Is there anyway to register a script which has already been run? We often need to deploy hot fix in our database to resolve immediate issues (e.g. new index to improve performance) without waiting for script to be checked in our source control repository and run by flyway.  We need those scripts registered but we can't run them again, which is going to fail.